# Google Play: "Production" "Active" app not in store, "View On Google Play" link doesn't work

Tags: android, google-play

I published a game to production in Google Play Console, and the console page for it says "Production" and "Active", and has a link to "View On Google Play", but the link doesn't work, and just goes to a "We're sorry, the requested URL was not found on this server." page.

[image]

[image]

I've seen other posts here on SO with similar problems, but they all say that it's taking a long time for the app to change from "In Review" to "Production", whereas my app is already in "Production" but doesn't show up in the store.

Am I missing something? Is there still normally a wait after the status says "Production" and "Active"?

Google's documentation says that once an app's status says "Production" it's available on Google Play. https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9859751

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this is that the app page in Google Play Console had been set long ago to "managed internal only" in "Advanced Settings", probably with the thought that that would make it testable internally, and then it could be switched back to public later. However, if this is set, you can NEVER make the app public, and have to start all over with a new Google Play Console app entry (with a different bundle ID!) if you want a public version.

[image]

You can even set the app to "closed beta" and invite outside people to test it, or set it to "open beta" or "production", and it'll look like it's available to the world, but it isn't actually. And there's no indication anywhere that it's set that way, except this tiny notification on the "Open Beta > Testers" tab.

[image]